# How to use one function instead of many only changing the div values of it?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I am trying to make a questionary, with dynamic questions. The application should give some questions and when the question is answered the "next" button appears and based on your answer you get the next question.

Basically idea is to make a troubleshooting tool where the customer could answer the questions and in the end could get the proposal of what could be the issue.

I have simplified the questions just to keep it simple and understandable.

I have managed to make it work, but the problem is that for each question i have to write a seperate function only with different values.

So I wonder if there is a way to make this work with only one function where valus could be dynamic and skip copy pasting the same code over and over and changing it's values. All the values have a shortname and the number, so mabye it is possible to substract or increment them ? In that case how to do it in one function instead of many.

My jquery original function:

```
   $("input[name='group1']").click(function () {    
    $("#next").show();
});

$("#next").click(function () {  
    if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").val() == 'opt1') {
        $('div:not(#q1)').hide();
        $("#q1").fadeIn(1000);

    } else if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").val() == 'opt2') {
        $("#q0").hide();
        $("#q2").fadeIn(1000);
    } 


});
```

Full example can be seen in JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2y0727d/1/)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After reading this few time i came up with idea. 
Is it possible to collect the input name, input value and the paragraphs id, and then save it as a variables inside the js file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an attribute to every radio button to know exactly the number. It's easier to check the value.

After doing that you can create a counter and just increment it in every `#next`click.

HTML:

```
<div id="q2" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Are you good on Call of duty ?</h2>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group3" id="rdio5" question="5" value="opt5">Yes</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group3" id="rdio6" question="6" value="opt6">No</label>
    <br>
    <p class="next" id="next2" style="display:none;">Next</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var c = 1;
$("#next").click(function() {
  if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").attr('question') == c) {
    $('div:not(#q1)').hide();
    $("#q1").fadeIn(1000);

  } else if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").attr('question') == c+1) {
    $("#q" + c-1).hide();
    $("#q" + c).fadeIn(1000);
  }
c++
});
```